# What is the right way to configure Ubuntu on VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vmware

When I try Installing Virtual box and configure Ubuntu in it..
It gives me an error that says :NO media Block Found

I Have VM ware installed as well.
Can some one help me out to Configure my Ubuntu on Virtualbox.

Also I have only 1 Gb of RAM and assigning 512mb for Ubuntu gives me a warning.

Comment: Assigning 50%+ of your ram to guest OS's is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
No Media Block Found
```

This means that when your VM boots it is not finding anything to boot.  In your case: you are setting up a new VM and have an empty/blank virtual hard drive.  YOu need to go into your settings and configure it so that it has your iso image or disc mounted so that the VM can boot from it initially.

If using iso:

```
Settings: CD/DVD-ROM
Check Mount CD/DVD Drive
Hit Iso Image File Radio Button
Browser your system for the iso
```

If using CD/DVD Disc:

```
Settings: CD/DVD-ROM
Check Mount CD/DVD Drive
Hit Host CD/DVD Drive Radio Button
Select appropriate drive if you have multiple
```

At that point the rest is installing ubuntu.

Comment: So how do I actually configure it?
I have assigned my hard drive to Primary slave.
And what about the Iso image should it be Secondary slave or Primary master?

Comment: See my answer, I added in steps.

Answer (score 1):

Need a little more info here, Pavitar...

- What is the host OS?
- What version of Ubuntu are you attempting to install?
- Have you attached the CD or ISO to the Virtual CD Drive? (So it can boot and install to the virtual HDD)?

Unless you have monster amounts of RAM, 50% is a BAD idea. I assign 50% of my RAM on a server that has 16GB RAM, but I wouldn't even attempt to run a VM on a machine with only 1GB RAM.

I definitely recommend a RAM upgrade if you expect to get any kind of decent performance out of your VM - and for that matter, your host (since 50% of your 1GB is allocated to the VM, your host only gets 512MB).

You may also want to check out https://askubuntu.com/ for Ubuntu-Specific help.

Comment: I run fedora and ubuntu Vm's with 256 ram for testing all the time and they run just fine.  If you want a usable OS environment that is a different case but it depends on the VMs usage.  Also, I run Vm's on my asus netbook which only have a gb of ram all the time and they run just fine, it comes down to the desired VM environment you need.

Comment: @Chris-thanx. 
@Mistiry- My host OS is Windows XP SP3.
And yes I have a live CD of Ubuntu 8.10 
I tried installing ubuntu via the CD 
but somehow it comes to 82% and jus stops.
I used to think that the problem persists 
because of the low memory ,but now as our friend Chris says
it works fine even on 256 mb RAM.
So now i don't know whats the exact problem.